# Java Remove all cases of .0

Tags: java, string, methods, replace, decimal

I want a filter to run through a string and eliminate all of the un-needed .0's from the doubles. I have already tried replaces, but cases like 8.02 turn into 82.

I have a feeling this has been done before, but I cannot find any help.

I am looking for a method that will take in a `String`, example: "[double] plus [double] is equal to [double]", where the [double] is a double that will need to be checked for the redundant decimal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove zeros only from the fractional part? Either leading or trailing, or any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say you have a string called s that contains text like you described. simply do:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([0-9])\\.0+([^0-9]|$)", "$1$2");
```

and you're done.

ok, so i edited this a couple of times. now it works though!

Comment: This is interesting. It worked fine earlier, but now it fixes all bug the last number. Eg: "10.0+1.0=11.0" becomes "10+1=11.0". Any way to fix this?

Comment: oh, didn't think of that :( but substringing isn't necessary. check out my edit, it takes care of that case as well!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not take away the trailing zeros before you construct them into your string? This way you could use the `DecimalFormatter` method someone posted earlier and then deleted.

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); 
String str = formatter.format("8.0200"); 
System.out.println(str);
```

*Give them credit for the code if they come back.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will remove all trailing zeros from the fractional part of a double value. If your requirements are somewhat different, you may need to modify it slightly.

```
final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to check:->");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double KEY_VALUE = 0.0;
        final Double TOLERANCE = 0.000000000001d;

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        double[] a = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                a[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            if (Math.abs(a[k] - KEY_VALUE) < TOLERANCE)
            {
                    continue;
            }
            newList.add(a[k]);
        }

        System.out.println(newList);
    }
}
```

---

You can specifically use `DecimalFormat` to truncate the specified number of decimal places, if you need such as follows.

```
double x=10.4555600500000;
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

Would return `10.46`.

Answer (score 0):

The other posts assume you're working with a short string containing only decimal.
Assuming you're working with large strings of text, you can use Pattern/Matcher classes  (I'm at work, so posting in a hurry. Check for errors)

Use this regex to replace:

```
/* >1 digits followed by a decimal and >1 zeros. Note capture group on first set of digits. This will only match decimals with trailing 0s, and not 8.0002 */
(\d+)\.0+
```

Replace with

```
/* First capture group */
$1
```

I'm unsure of the regex rules for Java, so use this as a concept to get what you want.